# Twitter Red/Blue Confusion

Tags: twitter

On Twitter I notice with some people the tweet button and their names are blue but with other people these things are red, why is this?

Answer (score 2):

People can set their own colour scheme for their profile in Twitter. The default is the typical Twitter blue, if you see a profile with a different colour they probably changed it.